# Page layout with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page layout something like this.

[image]

This is my HMTL structure -

```
<div id="content-three-cols">
    <div class="leftcol">

    </div>

    <div class="cols-content">
        <div class="banner">

        </div>

        <div class="two-cols">
            <div class="rightcol">

            </div>

            <div class="middlecol">

            </div>                  
        </div>              
    </div>      
</div>
```

This is my CSS code so far -

```
.leftcol {
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   min-height: 500px;
   width: 180px;
   background: #34ab2b;
}

.banner {
   background: #ffe400;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   float: left;
   width: 750px;
   height: 150px;
}

.middlecol {
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 600px; 
  background: #2b73ab;
}

.rightcol {
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 500px; 
  background: #b2540f;
  float: right;
}
```

Adding this styles I couldn't get my expecting output. Instead my desire result this code create a mess layout for me. Can anybody tell my how can I figure this out.

This is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chRkf/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple really, here is a quick demo i made, i will explain everything in a second.

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KsbmX/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="head"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}

.left, .right, .head, .center{
    float:left; // Float all the containers to the left so have a `inline` effect
}

.left{
    height:100%;
    width:25%; // Full width minus right and center width 
    background:orange;
}

.head{
    background:red;
    height:10%; // Height of header
    width:75%; // Full width minus left sidebar
}

.center{
    width:50%; // Full width minus both sidebar's width
    background:skyblue;
    height: 90%; // Full height minus header height
}

.right{
    width:25%; // Full width minus center and left width
    background:green;
    height:90%; // Full height minus header height
}
```

also note, you may need to have a [Clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) handy seeing as a lot of elements are floating in thin air.

Happy coding :)

> ## Clearfix...

Well take a look at this fiddle, everything is working fine

> http://jsfiddle.net/mqzJN/

Now if we add a float to the link like this

> http://jsfiddle.net/mqzJN/1

Then you can see the background is gone, because the `<div>` doesn't have any height any more because the link is floating in thin air.

So you use a clearfix to fix this, like in this fiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/mqzJN/2/

So any element that has a `float` you might wan't to add the clearfix class to the container of that element like in the last fiddle example.

Comment: can you tell me how this code work `.left, .right, .head, .center{
    float:left; // Float all the containers to the left so have a `inline` effect
}`

Comment: Connor, can you tell me how `clearfix` work and why it is use?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So can I know do I need to use `clearfix` class in my this layout?

Comment: At the moment I use some extra markup to handle this kind of issues - like this `<div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: You don't need to use it right now, but you might do, i don't know

Answer (score 1):

[image]here

The HTML:

```
<body>
        <div class="left">

        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div class="upper"></div>


            <div class="lower">
                <div class="innerLeft"></div>
                <div class="innerRight"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
.left {
    width: 25%;
    height:  450px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f00;
}
.right {
    width: 75%;
    height:  450px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #4cff00;
}
.upper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.lower {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.innerLeft {
   width: 65%;
   float: left;
   height: 350px;
   background-color: fff;
}
.innerRight {
   width: 35%;
   float: right;
   height: 350px;
   background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go! (http://jsfiddle.net/aV2Dn/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left_column"></div>
    <div id="top_bar"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right_column"></div>
</div>

#wrapper{
    width:500px
    height:500px;
    margin: auto;
}
#left_column{
    width: 100px;
    height:500px;
    background: #34ab2b;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#top_bar{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #ffe400;
}

#middle{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height:400px;
    background: #2b73ab;
}

#right_column{
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height:400px;
    background: #b2540f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. can I know which method is good `position` or `float`?

Comment: I always use position (relative and absolute). It gives you better control of the layout (and is quite simple to use).

Comment: @TNK I'm sure as you proceed through your coding adventures you will find this out for yourself. Just note that if you use `position:absolute` your going to be spending a lot of time, if you wan't it to be responsive..... whereas if you use `float` responsive comes with the package...